# UUID randomUUID output empty

Tags: slf4j, uuid

I used UUID to tie to some execution in Java so that i can keep tracking it in Splunk logs.

For whatever reason it's empty, here is my code:

```
try {
    String taskId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    MDC.put("request_id", taskId);
    MDC.put("auth_user", "myservice");

    ** some logic here **
 } finally {
     MDC.clear();
 }
```

In Splunk, I see this:

```
2018-02-02T00:00:05.905+0000 request_id= user=myservice level=INFO ...
```

The `request_id` is empty? Why is that?

The code was deployed to multiple boxes, and I setup cron job to run it every morning 3am. To avoid multiple instances running the same code, I put lock on the code using ShedLock, which guarantee only one box can run the code, by the time it finish, it passed the time scheduled in the cron job that I make sure the code is executed only once a day by one of the box.

Update:
turned out the setting in logback.xml is wrong, here is the before:

```
<property name="APPLICATION_PATTERN"
            value="%date{&quot;yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ&quot;, UTC} request_id=%mdc{requestId} user=%mdc{auth_user} level=%-5level logger=%logger %msg%n"/>
```

it expected mdc{requestId} not mdc{request_id}

Comment: check exception in cath(Exception ex)

Comment: String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString(); for me its fine.!

Comment: You don't mention which logging implementation you are using but whether it's JUL or Log4J or Logback or whatever, there'll be some sort of configuration file or configuration code which will include a statement of _how_ the MDC value for populating request_id should be extracted. I suspect that's where the issue lies so if you update your question to show your logging configuration it should be possible to spot the error.

Comment: @glytching, thanks for the tip, went back to check logback.xml and found the typo!

Comment: Yeah ... `s/requestId/request_id`